# AMD Radeon HD 7750 HW Acceleration?

Tags: gpu

Is it possible to get ATI Catalyst drivers and hardware acceleration working for a AMD Radeon HD 7750 in Ubuntu?

Comment: What kind of hardware acceleration are you talking about? 3D/OpenGL, video decoding/encoding, programmatically (OpenCL), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Ubuntu version are you running? HD 7750's are supported on 12.10 forward out of the box in 3D mode. That is my direct experience.

This is the latest Catalyst driver for Ubunutu 13.xx [ATI Radeon HD 7750](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English)

If you're running more than 2 monitors this may not work well. That is also my direct experience. I previously had a HD 4980 and ran the appropriate Catalyst drivers with dual monitors for several years. I just went to the HD 7750 for triple monitors and I am having difficulties getting the driver support ironed out. I am able to get it all running, but if I install the ATI Catalyst support it will not allow the third monitor to come up.

Just a heads up. Lastly, you can get older Catalyst versions at support.amd.com